# Name of the conversion symbol in C

Tags: c

What is the conversion code (%) in C-programming called?

I've been trying to find the actual name and not just "the percent sign/symbol."

Wish I could accept more than just one answer. Thanks again guys!

Comment: `remainder operator`.

Comment: Also refer to [Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: What is a conversion symbol supposed to do?

Comment: I don't think Modulo Operator is the name I was looking for. I know it's also the operator for module. I'll come back later, and post the name if I find it. Thanks for the always fast replies!

@RedX

It's the % symbol. When scanning for data you use it to let C know what to expect. I.e, %d for int, %s for string, %c for char, etc.

Comment: The `%` as you use it in printf and scanf for example is not defined by the language but by the printf and scanf format strings.  Manual pages refer to the character following `%` as a conversion specifier, but the character `%` itself has no special name. It is just called `%` (percent). http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf  See also the "Jargon file" http://www.catb.org/jargon/oldversions/jarg211.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it formatting symbol, being the d,e,f,x the format specifier, if you are not referring to it as an arithmetic operator. As an arithmetic operator you can call it module operator.

But the name, really depends on what it is used for.

For example if you use it with and equal operator like this "%=" in this expression `int a %= 5;` then you should called it module assignment, so as you can see, it really depends.

Comment: I'll accept your answer when I get back to my computer, since I can't accept an answer under a certain time limit, and I got to be somewhere. Unless someone gives me the name I'm looking for. :P Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`%` is remainder operator but when it comes together within the format string it makes a *conversion specification* with following a valid character (conversion specifier, any of `d, f, s, c` etc).

Comment: Technically this is not correct. The characters that come after the `%` are formally called the `conversion specifier`.  An entire combination (e.g. `%s`) is itself called a `conversation specification`. The symbol `%` itself to introduce a conversion specification does not receive a special name in any documentation http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?printf+3 '' Quote 1: `Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %, and ends with a conversion  specifier.`'' Quote 2: ''`%:    A '%' is written. No argument is converted. The complete conversion specification is '%%'.`''

Comment: @Brandin; Thanks for clarifying `conversion specifier` and `conversion specification`.

Answer (score 3):

[The character is called the “percent sign”.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_sign) I do not believe it has another name, the way a slash does (“solidus”).

The C standard does not use any name for it; it uses the character to speak for itself:

C 2011 (N1570) 6.5.5 5 says “… the result of the **%** operator is the remainder.”

C 2011 (N1570) 7.21.6 4 says “Each conversion specification is introduced by the character **%**.”

Comment: +1 for simply "the character %" as the C spec calls it during `scanf()` conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to the "*modulo operator*"

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Basically, it allows you to get an integer representation of the remainder.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 2;

int mod = a % b; // mod == 1, the remainder for 5 / 2
```